# Boostrap 4 extra small col width 100% not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-grid

I have developed a static HTML page with Bootstrap 4, using `col` equal with big screen but on `Extra small` screens, the col is not getting `100%` `width`. What did I forget?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div class="container">
     <div class="form-row">
        <!-- Grid column -->
        <div class="col col-6">
            <!-- Material input -->
            <div class="md-form">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="City">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Grid column -->

        <!-- Grid column -->
        <div class="col">
            <!-- Material input -->
            <div class="md-form">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="State">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Grid column -->

        <!-- Grid column -->
        <div class="col">
            <!-- Material input -->
            <div class="md-form">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Zip">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Grid column -->
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Extra small col width 100% not working

The columns aren't 100% width because `col` is the [**auto-layout column**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#auto-layout-columns) for the smallest `xs` screen size, therefore the columns will continue to shrink in width, and never stack vertically.

Just use **`col-sm`** instead...

https://www.codeply.com/go/xb7WffaSmS

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="form-row">
        <!-- Grid column -->
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <!-- Material input -->
            <div class="md-form">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="City">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Grid column -->

        <!-- Grid column -->
        <div class="col-sm">
            <!-- Material input -->
            <div class="md-form">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="State">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Grid column -->

        <!-- Grid column -->
        <div class="col-sm">
            <!-- Material input -->
            <div class="md-form">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Zip">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Grid column -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Also note, the **`-xs` infix has been removed** in Bootstrap 4. Now the smallest  classes are simple `col`, `col-6`, `col-12`, etc...